# Logic behind expiring JAR signing certificates

Tags: signing, client-certificates, jar-signing

My company uses a code signing certificate purchased from GoDaddy.  I use it to sign JAR files containing client UI applications.  Each year it expires and wreaks havoc among the Java Web Start users.

I can either recompile the software and generate new JARs, or I can 're-sign' the JARs with the new certificate.  There is really no nice way (that I know of) to re-sign a JAR (you must expand it, remove old certificate files, re-compress, re-sign).

The software itself does not change.  My question is:

If I originally compiled and signed the software with a legitimate certificate and, if the software does not change, why must I re-sign when the certificate expires?  If the software was validated at one time and does not change then why should its validity expire?

I would think the JAR would be more secure if it wasn't messed with periodically.